# CSS Style sheet not reflecting on my aspx

Tags: asp.net, css

i have the following CSS style sheet in Site.css

```
.img
{
    width: 1300px; 
    height: auto;
}
```

and the following codes in my default.aspx

```
<div class="img">
 <img src="http://files.g4tv.com/images/blog/2008/06/18/633493967095957891.jpg" alt="DOMO" />
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
```

how come my picture is not reflecting the width and height stated in the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying class to your division. If you want to select image inside division then
Change to:

```
.img img
{
    width: 1300px; 
    height: auto;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4dkUP/)

Answer (score 1):

Apply class on your `img` instead on that `div`

```
<div >
    <img class="img" 
         src="http://files.g4tv.com/images/blog/2008/06/18/633493967095957891.jpg"
         alt="DOMO" />
    <div class="desc">
                Add a description of the image here
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

You can create your css like this

```
img
{
    width: 1300px; 
    height: auto;
}
```

But it has a drawback that this css will be applied on every `img` in your document. So first one is better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

so my CSS style is 
'img
{
    width: 2900px; 
    height: auto;
}' 

and my aspx code is

'
<div >
    <img class="img" src="http://files.g4tv.com/images/blog/2008/06/18/633493967095957891.jpg" alt="DOMO" />
</div>
'

but how come is still not reflecting??

Answer (score 1):

In your style you are setting width for your div, which has the class "img".